# Finding Servers Public IP and Allowing Remote Access

Tags: ip, file-server

I want to turn a computer that I have lying around into a file server. The problem is that I cannot find my public IP. I have used services such as myip or even google, but they all point to the IP of the server of my ISP in another city.

Does anyone know:

1. How I can find my public IP and
2. How I can access my computer from outside my LAN?

Comment: What's wrong with myip? You forgot to hit the ENTER key?

Comment: `they all point to the ip of the server of my ISP, in another city`. How are you deciding that this isn't "your" public ip?

Comment: port forwarding is the solution.

Comment: Ott, how exactly is your answer useful? User454038 , you see extra information about the ip on myip, and other such websites.

Answer (score 1):

You can set **port forwarding** on your router: it uses *NAT* to redirect packets coming from *outside* the network to a host *inside* the network.

For example, say you have an FTP server on 192.168.1.104:21.
You could set your router to redirect all communication requests coming from outside on port 21 to 192.168.1.104:21 (or *any* host inside the network).

By setting this in your router interface, you can make any service residing on an internal host available to any host outside the network. To access the FTP server you would then type:

```
ftp -p yourpublicip:21
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good possibility that you don't have a static public ip address. A lot of ISPs won't provide you with a static address unless you have a business account. The way around this is to use Dynamic DNS if your router supports it. Just Google your router model and ddns to see how to setup your router. If your router doesn't support DDNS then depending on your setup you might be able to use your computer to update your dns record.

How DDNS works is there is a service which maps your domain name to your ip address and there is a program on either your router or one of your computers which updates the dns service periodically so that when your ip address changes your domain still points to your router. Beyond that you will need to forward the ports you want through your router or put the "server" in a DMZ.

I use the dynamic DNS provided by [dyn.com](http://dyn.com/dns) I thought they had a free limited version but I can't seem to find it on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Your public IP address is going to be readily available from quite a few different sources.  The easiest of which is to Google: *"What's my IP address"*.

There are also some fairly simple ways of getting it from the command line; normally via `cURL`.  The fastest and most reliable I've found is [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/).

```
 $ curl https://diagnostic.opendns.com/myip
 104.154.45.56
 $
```

Another one that's more memorable and has gotten me out of a pickle quite a few times is [ifconfig.me](http://ifconfig.me).  Be warned, though: it is slower than molasses and shouldn't be used in anything further than curiosity.  At the time of this writing, it timed out on me twice before it responded with my IP address.

```
 $ curl ifconfig.me
 104.154.45.56
 $
```

---

> How I can access my computer from outside my LAN

That's a little more involved of a question and relies heavily on how reliable you need it.  You'll need to pay for a domain name from a decent registrar if you want it to function correctly for extended periods of time (i.e. > 1 year).  But I get the feeling you don't need it for any real production environment.

I frequently get free `.tk` TLD names from [Freenom](http://www.freenom.com/) when I want to mock something up in a realistic or personal environment.  I'm not sure if they offer a dynamic DNS updating service, though.  I normally use [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) for my DNS provider, and they do offer that service.  Below would be an example of the configuration file if you were using `ddclient`, which is a prominent dynamic DNS updating tools.

```
##
## CloudFlare (cloudflare.com)
##
ssl=yes 
protocol=cloudflare,                           \
server=www.cloudflare.com,                     \
login=myemail@foo.com                          \
password=my-cloudflare-api-key                 \
my-awesome-site.com,
```

<sup>*[CloudFlare Resources and downloads - Dynamic DNS Client: ddclient](https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads/)*</sup>

---

As a final caveat, don't forget to setup port-forwarding on your router to direct inbound packets to the listening ports on your private server!

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is a NAT address. It's a convertion of your private network to a public address. [NAT](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) You may try other websites.

For you to access that server you will have to set up a VPN and connect both, server and client.